# How to add CloudKit to a Swift Playground app

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground, swift-package-manager

Is it possible to add CloudKit to a Mac Swift Playground app? The simplicity of the Playground app is great for development, but I can't find a way to setup entitlements beyond what's provided in the GUI.

I'm open to something somewhat hacky, like using `Package.swift` `additionalInfoPlistContentFilePath`. The only reference I've seen to this is a [twitter thread](https://twitter.com/_inside/status/1475892120456241166), which suggested this is not a possible route. Ideally there would be something similar to this that worked for entitlements, like `additionalEntitlementInfoPlistContentFilePath`.

My current method requires keeping a `<project>.swiftpm` alongside a `<project>.xcodeproj`, symlinking all non-cloudkit code between them, and enabling cloudkit on the xcodeproj option. This works, but of course has the draw back of maintaining both the xcodeproj and swiftpm project, and at that point I might as well just use the xcodeproj.

Comment: Playgrounds can't use CloudKit, even in version 4.  It's one of the few restrictions on Playgrounds.  The hack above might work reliably, but as you point out you really aren't adding CloudKit to a playground but to a linked XCode project, and at that point everythign would be simpler, more reliable, and officially supported to just use a full project.